# How to set all values in a row in matrix to a specific value if that value already exists in row python

Tags: python, matrix

How can you change all elements in a row in a matrix to a certain value, if that same value exists in a random place in the row?
I want to find all elements '-3' in all rows and set all elements to that value.
Here's what I've got so far, but my loop doesn't seem to work. 
Afterwords I'm sorting all rows and deleting the first column. That works fine.

```
def computeFinalGrades(grades):
if len(grades) <=1 :    
    gradesFinal=grades
if len(grades) > 1 : 
    for i in range(len(grades)):
        if np.any(grades[i,:]) ==(-3) :
            b=np.zeros(np.shape(grades[1]))
            b[b==0]=-3
            grades[i,:]=b
    grades1=np.sort(grades)
    grades2=np.delete(grades1,0,axis=1)
    gradesFinal=roundGrade(grades2.mean(1))
return gradesFinal
print(computeFinalGrades(np.matrix([[-3,0,3],[5,3,4],[9,5,6],[6,5,8]])))
```

It should take the first row and replace all elements with '-3'

My expected output should be

```
[[-3.]
[4.]
[7.]
[7.]]
```

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: what do you mean by `all elements` and `that value`?

Comment: I mean, that I want all elements in a row to become a certain value (-3) if this value (-3) exists somewhere in the elements of the row.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
for i in range(grades.shape[0]):
 if any(j == -3 for j in grades[i,:]):
        grades[i,:] = -3
```

Answer (score 0):

np.any(grades[i,:]) always returns true so its obviously the wrong function to use. Why use numpy at all?

Also you should include the import line for people to test your code:

> ```
>  #!/usr/bin/env python
>  import numpy as np
> ```